# Query Sql Error

Tags: sql, mapbasic

I want to join these 5 tables with MapBasic, because i want to use in statistic :

```
Select * 
    From Malade, Maladie, Ilot, Etat_Ilot, Pauvreté
    Where 
        Malade.Maladie = Maladie.ID_maladie 
        And Malade.Ilot = Ilot.ID_Ilot 
        And Malade.Classe_Pauvreté = Pauvreté.Classe 
        And Ilot.Etat_Ilot = Etat_Ilot.ID_Etat_Ilot 
    Into TIAC_EXP
```

When i excute it i get this error message:

```
"Incorrect tables are joined, Invalid Join Condition in WHERE Clause"
```

Can you tel me why ?

Comment: Please **edit** the question to give some indication of the database in use, and why this is appropriate to a GIS (vice database) forum.

Answer (score 1):

The SQL language of MapInfo Pro/MapBasic is some what limited when it comes to joins.

You can join multiple tables, but there is one basic rule that you need to follow, and looking at your SQL Select I doubt it's possible:

You need to "join" the first table to the second table, the second table to the third table, and so on.

Like this:

```
Select *
   From TABLEA, TABLEB, TABLEC, TABLED
   Where TABLEA.ID = TABLEB.AID
   And TABLEB.ID = TABLEC.BID
   And TABLEC.ID = TABLED.CID
   Into SOME__RESULT
```

In your case you probably need to do the joins in two or three SQL Select statements and save each result into a temporary table and then join the result set to each other:

```
Select * 
   From Maladie, Malade, Ilot, Etat_Ilot
   Where Maladie.ID_maladie = Malade.Maladie 
   And Malade.Ilot = Ilot.ID_Ilot 
   And Ilot.Etat_Ilot = Etat_Ilot.ID_Etat_Ilot 
   Into TIAC_EXP_A
Commit Table TIAC_EXP_A As "C:\TIAC_EXP_A.tab"
Close Table TIAC_EXP_A
Open Table "C:\TIAC_EXP_A.tab"

Select * 
   From TIAC_EXP_A, Pauvreté
   Where TIAC_EXP_A.Classe_Pauvreté = Pauvreté.Classe 
   Into TIAC_EXP
```

Something like the above